# Java Date Format in "args"

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, args

So, I'm using JD-GUI to decompile some Java class files which doesn't have any documentation. This Java Application is running on a Windows Server and running via taskscheduler with a `cmd` file (I don't know exactly what, intern here).

If some one who worked with an args command can help me out, I would really appreciate it. The code snipped is attached, all what I want is to understand is what the **for loop is doing at the end of the code**.

```
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  try
  {
  List violationList = new ArrayList();

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  Date inputDate = new Date();
  cal.setTime(inputDate);
  cal.set(11, 0);
  cal.set(12, 0);
  cal.set(13, 1);

  inputDate = cal.getTime();

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
  for (int ii = 0; ii < args.length; ii++) {
    if (args[ii].equals("-date")) {
      inputDate = dateFormat.parse(args[(ii + 1)]);
    }
 }
```

Here is the `run.cmd` file along with Java files I found. Notice there is `.Main` mention at the last line, something to do with those `%1` and `%2`.

RUN.CMD

```
@ECHO OFF
set CP=.;realapplication.jar; commons-       logging.jar;msbase.jar;mail.jar;activation.jar;log4j.jar;
set CP=%CP%sqljdbc4.jar;msutil.jar;spring-1.2.6.jar;commons-httpclient-2.0.1.jar;weblogic_8.1.jar;
set CP=%CP%zipfilemanager.jar;kmoscommon.jar;sessionpool.jar;kmosdao.jar;gendao.jar;rowset-1.0.1.jar;
java -classpath "%CP%" com.adnan.Main %1 %2
```

Comment: The Java code scans all arguments passed on the command line searching for "-date". If it finds it, parses the following argument which is expected to be formatted as a date, and creates a Date object out of it.

The script passes the first two arguments that were passed to the script down to the java code, so if any of those contains "-date <date>", that date will be parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop goes over the command line arguments and searches for a pair of arguments in the form of `-date 16/11/81` (the given date is just an example, of course). Once it finds it, it parses the second argument (`16/11/81`, in this case) to a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and stores it in the `inputDate` variable. If the `-date` argument is omitted, today's date will be used.

Comment: `%1` and `%2` from the cmd will pass two args (for that purpose). It seems that this is an optional way to run the script with an old date, should something have gone awry, otherwise it always takes the current time.